Multiples \index (imakeidx) changes the behaviour of \item_01
I've got a simple problem using the \index command with the imakeidx package. As soon as I repeat the entry, I lose the layout of \item_01 (in the ist file below, a simple \hrule).
My simple.ist file :
item_01 "\\vspace{0.5em}\\hrule\\vspace{1em} \\subitem "

My MWE with a \hrule command to illustrate the problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, options=-s simple.ist]
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\index{aaa}
\index{aaa!bbb}
\index{aaa!ccc}
\index{ddd}
\index{ddd!eee}
\index{ddd!fff}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\index{aaa} % erase the item_01 behaviour ?
\index{aaa!bbb}
\printindex
\end{document}



Just so people don't get confused, perhaps you should more clearly explain what the expected behavior should be?

Perhaps add the comment % % delete the next four lines to the the expected output above \newpage as the existence of those lines seems to affect things

But it also happens if one remove imakeidx and use makeindex directly

From how I read The LaTeX Companion 3rd edition, I would agree that item_01 should be triggered at the first subitem level in a block

it looks as if you found a bug. @daleif reported it already on the texlive list.

Too long for a comment, this might make it clearer what is going on
I get the result below. As we can see it seems item_1 vs item_01 triggers when there is more than one page number?
\begin{theindex}

  \item aaa, 1, 2
 \subitem (item\_1) bbb, 1, 2
 \subitem (item\_1) ccc, 1

  \indexspace

  \item ccc
 \subitem (item\_x1) fff, 1

  \indexspace

  \item ddd, 1
 \subitem (item\_01) eee, 1
 \subitem (item\_1) fff, 1

\end{theindex}

Here is the modified MWE
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{simple.ist}
item_1 "\n \\subitem (item\\_1) "
item_01 "\n \\subitem (item\\_01) "
item_x1 "\n \\subitem (item\\_x1) "
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, options=-s simple.ist]
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1} 
\index{aaa}
\index{aaa!bbb}
\index{aaa!ccc}
\index{ddd}
\index{ddd!eee}
\index{ddd!fff}
\index{ccc!fff}

% delete the next four lines to the the expected output

\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\index{aaa} % erase the item_01 behaviour ?
\index{aaa!bbb}

\printindex
\end{document}

